# Longchain relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have three models `Post.php` being primary model that is in relation with other two model `Category.php` & `Tags.php` that are in following manner:

```
 class Post extends Model
{
    public function category() 
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
   }

   public function tags()  
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tags');
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the category name of the blog posts that has same tag name.

This is what I've tried:

```
 public function getByTag($tag)
{
    $tags = Tag::where('name','=',$tag)->first();
    $posts = $tags->posts()->get();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo($post->category->name.'<br>');
    }
}
```

The above code somewhat does the job *(repeats previously used category as it is printing category of each posts)*. And I want to print all related category name once only.

I would be very thankful if anyone could suggest the best query approach for the output I'm looking for ?

**Updated**
Added table structure

```
    posts
   id - integer
   title - string
   content - text
   category_id -integer
category
   id - integer
   name - string
tags
   id - integer
   name - string
posts_tags
   id - integer
   post_id - integer
   tag_id -integer
```

Comment: Can you please show me your table structure of three?

Comment: What is `$tests` var? Also, what relationship is beetwen posts and blogs?

Comment: you want to use hasManyThrough to create a relation between blog and categories https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$tags = Tag::where('name','=',$tag)->first();
$posts = $tags->posts()->with('category')->get(['category_id']);
$categories = $posts->pluck('category')->unique();
```